# Create column and rows value use batch script windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

so currently i want to add column and static rows value in excel file with windows batch script.

My progress still only able add new column and set value for entire column, don't know yet for set column name.
Here is my script:

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (myfile.csv) do (
  echo(%%a^|mystaticvalue
))>"myfile.csv"
```

Is it possible to set column name in batch script without VBS/python?

Comment: This is unclear, you are not giving example input and expected output. So we have to guess by the code alone.

Comment: My apologize, example in my excel file there're 3 columns. I uploaded an example in this url : https://imgur.com/Ksart4x so exactly i want to add 4th column. Column name set as Product type, and all rows value set as Sparepart. @GerhardBarnard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to treat the first line differently. Use a flag to check if it's the first line.
Also, you can't write to the same file, you are reading from. Use a temp file and rename (`move`) it when done.

```
@echo off
set "hdr="
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (myfile.csv) do (
  if not defined hdr (
    echo(%%a^|ProductType
    set "hdr=done"
  ) else (
    echo(%%a^|mystaticvalue
  )
))>"myfile.tmp"
move /y "myfile.tmp" "myfile.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your help, it works perfectly! Btw, where u got advance documentation for command in batch script?

Comment: Take a look at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) (and bookmark it) Also you can get help with each command at the command line with the `/?` switch (for example `for /?`)

Comment: I see, one more question. How to add date value in file name from above code? i try add move /y "myfile.tmp" "myfile-%date%.csv" but not working

Comment: because date has special characters that are not allowed try `echo myfile-%date:/=-%`